# Open a non-http url with window.open

Tags: javascript

```
window.open("http://www.w3schools.com") // open properly   

window.open("www.w3schools.com","_blank") // it adds my localhost as prefix.
```

I know it should work in that way, but I want that to open as a url without prefix. Is there any way to do that ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
        <p>Click the button to open a new browser window.</p>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        window.open("www.w3schools.com");
    }
    </script>
    < a href="google.com">direct</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Problem statement - User's will enter the url like "abcd.com" in the application and I will have to relate that to a link. Most of the user's does not enter full url.

**based on the input below I have added this**

```
<button onclick="myFunction('facebook.com/')">Try it</button>

<script>
    function myFunction(url) {
            var check = url.substring(0, 4);
            if (check == "http") {
                     window.open(url);
            } else {
                window.open('//' + url);
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: For static code, this question makes little sense – you either want to open an external URL, or a relative one. Should this be about working with user input, i.e. the user types in `www.w3schools.com` somewhere, and you want to open that site – then you need some code that takes the user input, checks if the protocol is present, and if not adds it. (But that could still leave problems with sites that are available via HTTP or HTTPS only, how would you pick the right one?)

Comment: Yeah.. users just enter abcd.com.. I will have to relate that to a link. there lies problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A URL **must** have a scheme. If you use a relative URL then the scheme is computed from the current page. (If you use a relative URL which consists only of a path section, then you'll also take the hostname of the current page, and if the path itself is relative, you'll take the current pages path up until the last `/` too … which is what is happening in your example).

Browsers have, in recent years, taken to *not displaying the scheme in the address bar*, but the URL still must have a scheme (even if you can't see it).

Comment: Scheme-relative URLs would also work here, e.g. `//www.w3schools.com`.

Comment: Yes, but the URL will still have a scheme.

Comment: Yes, but you do not have to specify it in that case, so maybe that will suit the questioner better.

Comment: Thanks for your input. My real problem is user's will enter the url like "abcd.com", I will have to relate that to a link..

Comment: @rinuthomaz — Then you'll need to write code to convert it to a URL.

Comment: <button onclick="myFunction('facebook.com/')">Try it</button>

<script>
    function myFunction(url) {
            var check = url.substring(0, 4);
            if (check == "http") {
                     window.open(url);
            } else {
                window.open('//' + url);
            }
        }
</script>

**Any problem you see in above code?**